# Regular expression for Amazon S3 Object name

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

From the aws doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html , we know the characters that are allowed as part of the object name. I want to build a regular expression that should specify an object or a group of objects like this:

```
/abc/obj*
/abc/*
/*
/abc/obj1.txt
```

The regular expression I have created looks like this:

```
"((/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*((/[a-zA-Z0-9\\.]*(\\*)?)?))"
```

Apart from the additional symbols that need to be added inside square brackets, does this regular expression looks good or needs some more enhancements or simplification?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you regex doesn't quite work. For the case `/abc/obj.txt`, for example, it fails to match the `.txt` portion. See [A demo of your regex](https://regex101.com/r/fcwISa/2). Second, in the sub-expression `[a-zA-Z0-9\\.]`, you don't need the backslash characters; the `.` will be interpreted as the period character without them. Third, you should have `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end of your regex to make sure you match what you require and there is nothing extraneous in the input in addition. Fourth, you did not specify what language you are working with.

Here I am working with Python:

```
import re

tests = [
    '/abc/obj*',
    '/abc/*',
    '/*',
    '/abc/obj1.txt'
]

# the regex: ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+/)*(\*|([a-zA-Z0-9]+(\*|(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)))$

for test in tests:
    m = re.match(r"""
        ^                   # the start of the string
        /                   # a leading /
        ([a-zA-Z0-9]+/)*    # 0 or more: abc/
        (\*                 # first choice: *
        |                   # or
        ([a-zA-Z0-9]+       # second choice: abc followed by either:
            (\*|(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)))    # * or .def or nothing
        $                   # the end of the string
        """, test, flags=re.X)
    print(test, f'match = {m is not None}')
```

Prints:

```
/abc/obj* match = True
/abc/* match = True
/* match = True
/abc/obj1.txt match = True
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DVQNPM/1)

[image: Analysis of the regex]

But as I read the specification for object keys at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html, it does not appear that your test cases are valid examples since none of the examples shown there have leading `/` characters. It would also appear that the `*` character should be treated like any other character and can appear many times in any position. This makes the regex actually much simpler:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9!_.*'()-]+(/[a-zA-Z0-9!_.*'()-]+)*$
```

[image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/An2CFb/1)

New Code:

```
import re

tests = [
    'abc',
    '-/abc/(def)/!x*yz.def.hij'
]

# the regex: ^[a-zA-Z0-9!_.*'()-]+(/[a-zA-Z0-9!_.*'()-]+)*$

for test in tests:
    m = re.match(r"""
        ^                       # the start of the string
        [a-zA-Z0-9!_.*'()-]+    # 1 or more: ~abc*(def)
        (
            /
            [a-zA-Z0-9!_.*'()-]+
        )*                      # 0 or more of /~abc*(def)
        $                       # the end of the string
        """, test, flags=re.X)
    print(test, f'match = {m is not None}')
```

Prints:

```
abc match = True
-/abc/(def)/!x*yz.def.hij match = True
```

Comment: I have tried a program which seems to work:
 {
 string a = "/abc/lm/hh.txt"; 
 regex b("((/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*((/[a-zA-Z0-9\\.]*(\\*)?)?))");
 if ( regex_match(a, b) ) 
  cout << "String 'a' matches regular expression 'b' \n";}

Comment: @user3552519 Go to this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gf07uY/1) of your new regex and you will see that it does *not* work; it is not matching the *entire* input string for any of your test cases. And if the input string were `"/abc/lm/hh.txt-"`, would you see any difference? This is why I told you to put in the `^` and `$` characters at the beginning and the end of your regex. Did you even try my regex? You should be using regex01.com for testing.

Comment: And you still have backslashes within `[]`, which is unnecessary. You asked for "enhancements and simplifications" but then ignored one important enhancement and a simplification, even if you don't care for my regex.

Comment: Your regex will match `/abc.txt*`, mine will not. I did not think that was your intention. This is the problem when you do not have a *precise* specification for what you are looking for but only provide a few examples. So which is it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It actually works fine. Can you help me build a regex that will take care of the allowed characters for an Object as given in the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html . Also, I want to know how you build the regex graph as you have shown in your answer.

Comment: @user3552519 I used [Regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/) to build the regex graph. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One question. Since you have used symbols ".*", won't it interfere with the fact that .* actually will mean any character can be specified any number of times. Do we need to put extra slash to show they are specified separately.

Comment: @user3552519 Characters specified within `[` and `]` brackets lose their special regex meaning except for `^` when it appears as the first character and `-` when it appears between characters to denote a range (notice that I specified `-` as the *last* character within `[]`). So `[.*]` is equivalent to `(\.|\*)`. This is why I kept on saying you did not need the backslashes within `[]`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for this. Will mark the issue as resolved.

Comment: I suppose, from the doc, characters like "&$@=;:+,?" also need the inclusion.

Comment: @user3552519 I don't know what your ultimate purpose is, but if you are able to limit yourself to just the characters already specified, then you might be better of doing so. However, if this is something you have no control over and have to include also *the characters to avoid*, then throw these additional characters into the `[]` being sure that the `-` character remains the last character and `^` is not the first. You *will* have to backslash escape the `]` character and the \ itself. But, as the documentation states, you may have to encode these characters specially when you use the name.

Comment: `[\x00-\x1F\x7F]` for all ascii characters in the range 00-1F hex and 7F hex.

Comment: Thanks again. Got it. Actually this is something I don't have a control on the input.  So, I need to take care of these corner cases as well.